# Is someone familiar with this USB debugging error on Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, usb-debugging

I am trying to usb-debug Xamarin.Forms app with my physical android device Samsung a51.

This error keeps coming. Does anyone known a solution or things worth trying to solve this?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression StateError  XARDF7024: System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)   at System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound, WIN32_FIND_DATA& data)   at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean recursive, Boolean checkHost)   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.RemoveDirFixed.RunTask() 0

Comment: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`. You have passed in an invalid path.  Your question title could be improved, for more views, to label the actual problem. 

You are best off posting the code/path you passed into the directory delete command.

Comment: @IAmGroot  I have not passed in any path. Just created an application and trying to debug in device as it is. sorry, do you know hot to change this "path" and where it is described?

Comment: Thats odd then. Im not familiar with xamarin, just android. Hopefully someone can help. You could see if it happens on a fresh app. I assume the app runs fine without debugger?

Answer (score 1):

How I resolved this. My thought is the directory structure was too long. My path was C:\Users\dwain.DESKTOP-PBV6NB0\Downloads\xamarin-samples\xamarin
samples\GetStarted\Tutorials\LocalDatabaseTutorial\LocalDatabaseTutorial\

So to solve the issue I created a new folder eg Xamarin copied the LocalDatabaseTutorial folder started the csprog added the Android and IOS projects which created a new .sln file
Had to remove old references and add the reference to the other projects Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully figured out what is going on but it appears to have something to do with the directory structure your app resides in. I created a project with a directory structure like C:\Users\test\Desktop\testmobileproject\Mobile and it deploys to the device over USB. However, if you create a project with a directory structure like C:\Users\test\Desktop\myapp.mobile.project\Mobile you get the error. Maybe someone else with more knowledge can tell us why, but simplifying my directory structure and project solution name fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was run out of memory on laptop causing this issue.